# Dynamic loaded JARs/etc. in same JVM container

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I have a little bit weird question, and I probably didn't phrase it right, but the idea is:
I have WAR deployed in Tomcat container which integrates with few third-party systems.

I would like implementation of every third party system to be deployed in the same Tomcat (JVM Container). May be as a JAR.
I want WAR to use this JAR really effectively (speed, load, memory usage, etc.)
I do not want to restart Tomcat when I add new JAR.

What's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely add/update JARs on the fly without reloading. There are some very specific circumstances where you'll probably get away with adding a new JAR but it is rather hit and miss.

The best you'll be able to achieve is add the JAR to WEB-INF/lib and reload the web application (rather than restarting Tomcat). End users may see a pause in request processing while the web application restarts but you should not see any dropped requests. Note this only works for updating the classes and JARs deployed with a web application. If you change the WEB-INF/web.xml or META-INF/context.xml the application will still reload but there may be dropped requests.